# Get the list if subscriptions of an Azure Active Directory user during the build of an Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I want to add a validation step in an Azure Devops pipeline in which I wanna check the identity of the user who created the pull request. I wanna check the list of subscriptions to which this user is attached , is there an API to get this information ?

Comment: Hi @niko, have you already tried the following steps? Does it do some help? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

I created an Azure AD Application and consented API permissions:

[image]

I generated **code parameter** using the below endpoint:

```json
GET
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=redirect_uri
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
&state=12345
```

A sign-in screen will appear like below. After signing in the code value will be generated:

[image]

**To generate the token, I used parameters like below:**

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

 

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:Client_ID
client_secret:Client_Secret
scope:https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
redirect_uri:redirect_uri
code:code
```

[image]

**To get the list of subscriptions the user belongs to, try the below query:**

```json
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01
```

[image]